# Passing arguments to Ruby methods

Tags: ruby, methods, syntax

It seems that arguments can be passed to certain Ruby methods by appending the arguments after the method, and separating the two by a space. I'm trying to understand the mechanism that makes this happen. This is how arguments are passed to scripts in the command line. Why does the following statement work in Ruby?

```
item = 'orange'
fruits = ['orange', 'grapefruit', 'apple']
x = fruits.include? item
puts x
```

And why does the following statement not work?

```
item = 'orange'
fruits = ['orange', 'grapefruit', 'apple']

x = fruits.include? item ? 'You picked a fruit' : 'You did not pick a fruit'

puts x
```

Comment: In Ruby, you can omit parentheses when calling methods. `fruits.length` is the same as `fruits.length()`. Likewise, `fruits.include? item` is the same as `fruits.include?(item)`.

Comment: Makes sense. I edited the question to add a second statement. I suppose the second statement does not work as intended because the ternary statement is passed in as arguments to the `include?` method?

Comment: `x = fruits.include? item ? 'You picked a fruit' : 'You did not pick a fruit'` is evaluated as `x = fruits.include? (item ? 'You picked a fruit' : 'You did not pick a fruit')` -> `x = fruits.include? "You picked a fruit"` returning `false`. You can use `x = fruits.include?(item) ? 'You picked a fruit' : 'You did not pick a fruit'` or `x = (fruits.include? item) ? 'You picked a fruit' : 'You did not pick a fruit'` to disambiguate (I would recommend the former).

Comment: @ArunKumarMohan thanks that makes sense! Could you paste your comments as an answer and I will accept it?

Comment: You can omit the parens in most, but not all cases, for example the following will raise a syntax error because the comma is ambiguous (is it passing multiple arguments to include, or adding another entry to the array?) `x = [fruits.include? item, fruits.include? item2]`

Comment: Similarly you must use parens when passing a block in the one-liner format, e.g. `arr.each_slice 2 { |slice| puts slice }` is invalid but `arr.each_slice(2) { |slice| puts slice }` is valid

Comment: @maxpleaner Good point. Another example: `0..9 === 1` will raise `ArgumentError (bad value for range)` since it's evaulated as `0..(9 === 1)` (`0..false`). `(0..9) === 1` will return the expected result. Note that it's the same as `(0..9).===(1)`. The `===` is a method defined in the `Range` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Examine the AST with Ripper

In Ruby, parentheses are largely optional except when needed to avoid ambiguity, such as when passing arguments to methods that take a block. Under the hood, mainline Ruby has a lot of moving parts that tokenize and parse the code you write. One of the most useful is the [Ripper module](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Ripper.html) (documented [here](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.0.1/libdoc/ripper/rdoc/Ripper.html)) which enables you to see the abstract syntax tree that Ruby produces from your code.

Here are two versions of your code as Ruby sees them. You can see from the S-expressions that the failing version is different from the non-failing version. In irb:

```
Ripper.sexp %q{x = fruits.include?(item) ? 'You picked a fruit' : 'You did not pick a fru
it'}
#=> 
[:program,
 [[:assign,
   [:var_field, [:@ident, "x", [1, 0]]],
   [:ifop,
    [:method_add_arg,
     [:call,
      [:vcall, [:@ident, "fruits", [1, 4]]],
      [:@period, ".", [1, 10]],
      [:@ident, "include?", [1, 11]]],
     [:arg_paren, [:args_add_block, [[:vcall, [:@ident, "item", [1, 20]]]], false]]],
    [:string_literal, [:string_content, [:@tstring_content, "You picked a fruit", [1, 29]]]],
    [:string_literal, [:string_content, [:@tstring_content, "You did not pick a fruit", [1, 52]]]]]]]]
```

```rb
Ripper.sexp %q{x = fruits.include? item ? 'You picked a fruit' : 'You did not pick a frui
t'}
#=> 
[:program,
 [[:assign,
   [:var_field, [:@ident, "x", [1, 0]]],
   [:command_call,
    [:vcall, [:@ident, "fruits", [1, 4]]],
    [:@period, ".", [1, 10]],
    [:@ident, "include?", [1, 11]],
    [:args_add_block,
     [[:ifop,
       [:vcall, [:@ident, "item", [1, 20]]],
       [:string_literal, [:string_content, [:@tstring_content, "You picked a fruit", [1, 28]]]],
       [:string_literal, [:string_content, [:@tstring_content, "You did not pick a fruit", [1, 51]]]]]],
     false]]]]]
```

Since Ruby treats almost everything as an expression that returns a value, the order of operations can affect how the parser forms expressions. The ternary operator must ultimately evaluate as three expressions, and if you use what the parser considers ambiguous syntax it will cause problems.

### See Also

- [parse.y](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/parse.y)

Comment: Thank you, this is a very comprehensive answer. I now understand that in the second example, the ternary statement is being passed as arguments to the `include?` function.